# DC for Hat of Disguise if you are a spellcaster

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

What is the DC for Hat of Disguise if you are a spellcaster? If you are a wizard with intelligence modifier +5 you have just 8+5 or you have to add also proficiency?

I know that if you are not a spellcaster you have 8+proficiency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The wizard uses their spellcasting ability as usual

Dungeon Master's Guide, p141, under "Spells":

> A magic item, such as certain staffs, may require you to use your own spellcasting ability when you cast a spell from the item. If you have more than one spellcasting ability, you choose which one to use with the item.

Note that a Hat of Disguise is such an item even if it is not explicitly stated to use one's spellcasting ability ([sage advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/11/27/hat-of-disguise-dc/)).

A wizard could, therefore, add their intelligence modifier along with their proficiency to the DC, as if they were casting the spell from their spellbook as a normal spell. For any character with a spellcasting ability, the DC is 8 + proficiency + spellcasting ability modifier. For characters without a spellcasting ability, you are correct that it is simply 8 + proficiency.

Comment: I am skeptical on this. The ones that require or allow you to use your own spellcasting ability modifier are explicitly called out in the item's description.

Comment: @Slagmoth it's backed up [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/11/27/hat-of-disguise-dc/)

Comment: That should be included in this answer as the current verbiage is actually incorrect. And as I was putting into my own answer it is likely an oversight in the errata, which it is still not included there as well.

Comment: @Slagmoth I added it to the answer. For what it's worth, I think requiring one to cast a spell requiring the ability is itself a clear requirement of the spellcasting ability, but since it's in the Sage Advice I think it's the best to put it in for clarity.

Comment: @kviiri I disagree, only certain, specific items allow you to do it and they are called out in their descriptions (barring errors obviously), example Wand of Paralysis did not include a DC or the verbiage to allow you to use your own stats, it was later included in the errata. Point is that until it is explicitly detailed/ruled officially there is no way to know one way or another.

Comment: @Slagmoth Ok, I get the point